# Como definir uma cor de fundo e bordas para meu botão além dos estados pressionado e não pressionado no botão com?

Tags: java, android

Eu gostaria de além de meu botão ter uma borda inferior mais que tivesse os estados do botão a exemplo pressionado, não pressionado seria outra cor...

Eu estou tentando fazer tudo isso no meu xml do drawable para setar um background para meu botão. Segue xml do drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#362E2E" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="3dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#2a5aa4" />
    </shape>
</item>
<selector >

    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="#362E2E" android:state_focused="true"/>

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="#362E2E"/>

</selector>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira seria fazer programaticamente. Exemplo:

```
private boolean isChecked
```

Alterar a cor do botão quando for clicado

```
    button_1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(isChecked == true){
                button_1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_1));
                isChecked = false;
            }else {
                button_1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_2));
                isChecked = true;
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar a borda no botão tem uma tag chamada stroke e para que haja apenas a borda inferior, é preciso negativar os atributos top, right e left da tag item.

O drawable ficaria assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:bottom="-10dp" android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:angle="270" android:color="#a0e1" />

                <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#5c3708" />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp" android:top="-10dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:angle="270" android:color="#a0a67637" />

                <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#5c3708" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```